# Shot His Way Into

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about "shoot one's way into" [here](http://news.yahoo.com/newtown-shooters-history-reviewed-report-064530051.html):

> Lanza killed his mother then ***shot his way into*** the Newtown school on Dec. 14, 2012, and gunned down 20 children and six educators before committing suicide.

I checked dictionaries, and couldn't find the phrase "*shoot one's way into*".  Could this be some regional idiom or journalistic jargon?

Comment: @snailboat  What is a *productive pattern*?

Comment: Some examples,  "bulldozed his way into the end zone", "shoved his way to the front", and "danced his way into first place".

Comment: Yes, not every usage will be found in a dictionary.

Comment: @meatie, in addition to dictionaries, you can try Google's `ngram` search; for example: `* his way into` will show examples of the pattern.

Comment: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=34927410

Comment: Well it's not an example of journalists twisting language... if that's what you're asking. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not a regional idiom, or an idiom of any kind. It is not journalistic jargon.